# How to turn a string into a variable? (TI-84)

Tags: ti-basic

I'm trying to turn a string into a variable on my TI-84.

For example,

```
"XYZ"→Str0
fnInt(X²,sub(Str0,1,1),0,1)→A
```

But it's not letting me.

I know this seems like a really inefficient way of doing it (why not just do `fnInt(X²,X,0,1)`?), but in my program this would be very, very useful.

So is there a way to turn a string into a variable?

Comment: Wow, people are still doing TI programming? I was doing that 20 years ago in high school!

Comment: What calculator are you using?

Comment: @PGmath The TI-84+ SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use a string where `fnInt(` expects a variable.  The only thing I can recommend is to use a bunch of if statements, using `I` as the index of the variable you're using from your string.  Basically, you'd have to write out these cases explicitly, since there's no way to make a string get interpreted as a variable for that function.

```
If I=1:fnInt(X²,X,0,1)→A
If I=2:fnInt(X²,Y,0,1)→A
If I=3:fnInt(X²,Z,0,1)→A
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to avoid, but if that's the only way, I'll grin and bear it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string as some function and want to evaluate it for some values, you can always store it to `Y1`, set the variables in it to what you want, and then just use `Y1` as your evaluated function.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, though. I need to turn a string into a variable so that I can use that variable as the variable of integration for `fnInt(`.